# How to sync time between 2 systems with millisec accuracy?

Tags: java, javascript, time, synchronization

I need to measure the time lag between, the user click on a link and when the sever starts processing the request.The problem is syncing time between server and client to millisecond accuracy.I can't reset the time on server,i can only change the client time to be in sync with the server.In client i'm using javasript to get current time in millis and in server java.Any ideas to do this would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, the most accuracy you can achieve is by using the ntp protocol.
I would suggest you to use a ntp server inside your own network (and to synchronize the two machines against that server), so you minimize the delays in sinchronizations.

Anyway, I have doubts if this will be able to guarantee accuracy up to milliseconds.

Answer (score 1):

I 've +1ned @jap1968 for the NTP mention, and I suggest you two interesting readings :

[a paper on NTP precision](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.32.2500&rep=rep1&type=pdf)

[a well known post](http://ejohn.org/blog/accuracy-of-javascript-time/) from John Resig about javascript Time accuracy

These will give you some insights about how time could be measured accurately

You can find better protocol than NTP [as there](http://lecs.cs.ucla.edu/Publications/papers/broadcast-osdi.pdf), but you'll be limited to what your system can do (precision of your time source and the process to retrieve it in your software).